# The doctor found that he was bitten/had been bitten by a snake

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> The doctor found that he was bitten by a snake.

The correction of the above sentence is given as:  **had been bitten** in place of **was bitten**.
My query is:
**had been** means an action which continued from the past to the present. But, the sentence expresses an activity happened in the past and finished in the past. There is no continuity till the present, then why the correction of the sentence is **had been bitten**?

Comment: You're mixing up Past Perfect and Present Perfect. Just re-read about these tenses. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle  can you suggest me a good book with all the explanations.

Comment: It's basic grammar, just any basic-level textbook will do, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The perfect aspect, whether present or past, establishes some relation between the two events:

Present Event..........Past Event

Past Event.............Event farther in the past.

I see I've been bitten.

I saw I'd been bitten.

The act of noticing (becoming aware of) is the reference action here, and it is connected by the perfect to that which is being noticed, the being bitten.